# I get an error when trying to use auto-py-to-exe to export an Ursina based game

Tags: python, python-3.x, ursina, auto-py-to-exe

I'm using the ursina module for my game. When I try to run the exe file I made with auto-py-to-exe, it gives me this error:

```
failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled 
    exception: No graphics pipe is available!
    Your Config.prc file must name at least one valid panda 
    display library via load-display or aux-diplay. 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
      File "ursina\main.py", line 28, in __init__
      File "direct\showbase\ShowBase.py", line 339, in __init__
      File "direct\showbase\ShowBase.py", line 1024, in 
    openDefaultWindow
      File "direct\showbase\ShowBase.py", line 1059, in 
    openMainWindow
      File "direct\showbase\ShowBase.py", line 769, in 
    openWindow
      File "direct\showbase\ShowBase.py", line 749, in <lambda>
      File "direct\showbase\ShowBase.py", line 821, in 
    _doOpenWindow
      File "direct\showbase\ShowBase.py", line 650, in 
    makeDefaultPipe
      File "direct\directnotify\Notifier.py", line 130, in 
    error
    Exception: No graphics pipe is available!
    Your Config.prc file must name at least one valid panda 
    display
    library via load-display or aux-display.
```

```
from ursina import *
       import random
       from playsound import playsound
       app = Ursina()
       music = Audio('audio/Game_music.wav', loop=True)
       quantity = Entity(color=color.clear,position=(0,0,-30))
       points=Entity(color=color.clear,position=(0,0,-30))
       high= Entity(color=color.clear, position=(0, 0, -30))
       score_text = int(points.x)
       score_text2 = str(score_text)
       score = Text(text=score_text2, scale=5,position= 
       (-0.6,0.35,-18), color=color.black)
       score_top = Text(text="score:", scale=3,position= 
       (-0.65,0.45,-18), color=color.black); highscore_text = 
       int(high.x)
       highscore_text2 = str(highscore_text)
       highscore = Text(text=highscore_text2, scale=5, 
       position= 
       (0.6, 0.35, -18), color=color.black)
       highscore_top = Text(text="high score:", 
       scale=3,position= 
       (0.45,0.45,-18), color=color.black)
       respawn_texture = Entity(model='quad',scale= 
       (0.3,0.1),position= 
       (0,0,5),texture=load_texture('textures/Play_again'))    
       #menu_texture = Entity(model='quad',scale= 
       (0.3,0.1),position= 
       (0,-0.1,5),texture=load_texture('textures/Main_menu'))
       while quantity.x < 0:
       quantity.x = 0

       class background(Button):
          def __init__(self):
            super().__init__(
               model = 'cube',
               parent=scene,
               color=color.white,
               position=(0,0,4.5),
               scale = (30,30,2))

    def input(self, key):
        if self.hovered:
            if key == 'left mouse down':
                playsound("audio/screeching.m4a", block=False)
                camera.z = 4
                points.x = 0

    class Tile(Button):
        def __init__(self):
        quantity.x +=1
        placement = random.randint(-4, 4)
        potential_color_list=(color.red,color.blac)

        super().__init__(
            model = 'quad',
            parent=scene,
            color= random.choice(potential_color_list),
            position=(placement,quantity.x * 2 + 3,3),
            scale = 
    (random.uniform(0.1,3),random.uniform(0.5,3))),


    def input(self,key):
        if self.hovered:
            if key == 'left mouse down':
                if self.color == color.black:
                    playsound("audio/scored.m4a", block=False)
                    destroy(self)
                    quantity.x -=1
                    amount = random.randint(1,3)
                    multiplier_calculations = points.x / 10 + 1
                    Multiplier = int(multiplier_calculations)
                    points.x += Multiplier
                    score.Text = points.x
                    score_text = int(points.x)
                    score_text2 = str(score_text)
                    score.text = score_text2
                    if quantity.x <= 0:
                        if amount == 1:
                            Tile()
                        if amount == 2:
                            Tile()
                            Tile()
                        if amount == 3:
                            Tile()
                            Tile()
                            Tile()

                if self.color == color.red:
                    playsound("audio/screeching.m4a", 
                    block=False)
                    camera.z = 4
                if high.x < points.x:
                    high.x = points.x
                    highscore_text = int(high.x)
                    highscore_text2 = str(highscore_text)
                    highscore.text = highscore_text2
                    score.Text=points.x

        if camera.z == 4:
            destroy(self)
    def update(self):
        speed = points.x / 40 + 3
        if camera.z == -20 and points.x != 0:
            self.y -= speed * time.dt
        else:
            self.position=(0,4,3)
            self.color = color.black
        if self.y <= -6.5:
            if self.color == color.black:
                playsound("audio/screeching.m4a", block=False)
                camera.z = 4
                destroy(self)
            if self.color == color.red:
                destroy(self)
                quantity.x -= 1
                if quantity <= 0:
                    amount = random.randint(1,3)
                    if amount == 1:
                        Tile()
                    if amount == 2:
                        Tile()
                        Tile()
                    if amount == 3:
                        Tile()
                        Tile()
                        Tile()
        if camera.z == 4:
            score.text = '0'
            destroy(self)
            Tile()
            quantity.x = 0


    #class menu(Button):
    #    def __init__(self):
    #        super().__init__(
    #            model = 'quad',
    #            color=color.clear,
    #            parent=scene,
    #            position=(0,-0.05,5),
    #            scale = (0.09,0.03))

    #    def input(self, key):
    #       if self.hovered:
    #            if key == 'left mouse down':
    #                playsound("audio/bounce.m4a", block=False)
    #                points.x = 0
    #                quantity.x = 0
    #                camera.z = 8

    class play_again(Button):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__(
                model = 'quad',
                color=color.clear,
                parent=scene,
                position=(0,0,4.8),
                scale = (0.09,0.03))

        def input(self, key):
            if self.hovered:
                if key == 'left mouse down':
                    playsound("audio/bounce.m4a", block=False)
                    points.x = 0
                    quantity.x = 0
                    camera.z = -20
                    Tile()

    play_again()
    background()
    Tile()
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps to solve this **error** :

- Go to cmd and type auto-py-to-exe to open the gui
- Enter script location
- Select onefile
- Select either console based or window based
- Under additional files, click add folder and add:
  **panda3d-1.10.6.dist-info**, 
  **panda3d**,
  **direct**,
  **ursina-3.1.0.dist-info**,
  **ursina**,
- Go under "Advanced" to "–paths" and add folder "YOUR_PYTHON_FOLDER/Lib/site-packages/panda3d"